# CMake: Making a Visual Studio project for Windows Mobile

Tags: visual-studio, cross-platform, cmake

so far, my night has been extremely frustrating, trying to learn CMake. However, I'm slowly getting there. There are a couple of things bugging me though:

**1) Additional Library Directories**

I can either have this:

```
CMake: link_directories ("../../YoghurtGum/bin")
Output: AdditionalLibraryDirectories="..\..\YoghurtGum\bin\$(OutDir),..\..\YoghurtGum\bin"
```

Or this:

```
CMake: link_directories ("${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}../../YoghurtGum/bin")
Output: AdditionalLibraryDirectories="F:\Projects\YG3\Tests\Galaxians..\..\YoghurtGum\bin\$(OutDir),F:\Projects\YG3\Tests\Galaxians..\..\YoghurtGum\bin"
```

Or this:

```
CMake: link_directories ("${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/../../YoghurtGum/bin")
Output: AdditionalLibraryDirectories="..\..\YoghurtGum\bin\$(OutDir),..\..\YoghurtGum\bin"
```

While what I really want is this:

```
Output: "..\..\YoghurtGum\bin"
```

**2) Setting the platform name**

I haven't been able to set it, but I want it to be `Windows Mobile 5.0 Pocket PC SDK (ARMV4I)` instead of `Win32`.

**3) Setting the intermediate directory**

I want to have this:

```
IntermediateDirectory="intermediate"
```

instead of this:

```
IntermediateDirectory="Galaxians.dir\Release"
```

but nothing seems to work.

**4) Output file**

It should be:

```
OutputFile="$(OutDir)\$(ProjectName)_debug.exe"
```

instead of:

```
OutputFile="F:\Projects\YG3\Tests\Galaxians\bin\Debug\Galaxians.exe"
```

Any help on any of these issues would be much appreciated.

Comment: Hi, sorry I don't have any answers for you, as I'm in a similar situation and often frustrated by CMake, which has a documentation that looks very complete at the first glimpse but has lots of missing information whenever you need to understand it. Just as a hint for future questions: NEVER mention the word "frustration" in any of your questions, you are likely to get no answers. Or something like "This site is about programming, not frustration." But if you add "frustration" to your question title, things might turn out like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/719573 :) strange cultulture here

Answer (score 3):

To quote a famous (infamous?) line:

```
"You can't always get what you want."
```

**1) Additional Library Directories**

**2) Setting the platform name**

**3) Setting the intermediate directory**

These are just the way you've observed them. They are as they are, and you cannot change them with an "as-is" build/install of CMake.

Of course, having said that, CMake is an open source project. You could dive in and submit a patch that changes CMake to support these features. :-)

There are a few outstanding bugs (*cough*, feature requests) for CMake that, if fixed/implemented, would add support for other platform types. It will take quite a lot of effort to do it properly, though, and so far nobody has had the time/energy/funding to finish it off. See related CMake bug reports here:

- http://public.kitware.com/Bug/view.php?id=7919
- http://public.kitware.com/Bug/view.php?id=8102
- http://public.kitware.com/Bug/view.php?id=8486

**4) Output File**

This one you can change. Set the OUTPUT_NAME or OUTPUT_NAME_DEBUG target property.

- http://cmake.org/cmake/help/cmake-2-8-docs.html#prop_tgt:OUTPUT_NAME
- http://cmake.org/cmake/help/cmake-2-8-docs.html#prop_tgt:OUTPUT_NAME_CONFIG